# How to change certain cell's view across different view controllers swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, selected

I am building a recorder app that users can save their recordings.
How can I change a view of a certain cell in a UITableView to show users that this cell is being played and the cell with the same content in other ViewControllers can be changed simultaneously? 
Furthermore, when the audio player finished. The view can be changed back to default.

I have tried override setSelected, but the cell cannot stay selected when I reload the table view and the cell cannot be deselected by itself when audio has finished. I also cannot change the cell with the same content (same audio)' view simultaneously.
Is there a way to overcome this problem?

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    // Configure the view for the selected state
    if selected {
        print("task has began")
    } else if !selected {
        print("task has finished")
    }
}
```

The result will be like apple music or podcast that the cell with the same shows across the app will show whether or not it is being played.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make IBOutlet of View Inside xib

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var generaV: UIView!
}

set Identifier  = TableViewCell
```

**and call the Datasource Method in as many file you want and change the color like .red/.blue in in different VC**

Call the  Cell in ViewController

```
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

               if (audioEnded){ 
cell.generaV.backgroundColor  = UIColor.green
}
                 else {
   cell.generaV.backgroundColor  = UIColor.red
}


                return cell
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
I think the colour of every cell will be changed, and when the audio finished I cannot change it back. I only need the cells with the same content change across the app.

Comment: @David.P.JCHEN just  declare a variable on Top and make it true when it is finished and reload the cell will work. Have to reload the table whenever you want to change the view Color.